# Does Google Analytics data affect SEO?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics

I have several pages on my site that I did not include the Google Analytics code. Will it improve my site's Google ranking if I include the GA on all of my pages and increase the number of visits on GA?

Answer (score 8):

No. [Google Analytics does not affect your rankings](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLmO1GE4GvI&feature=player_embedded#at=14).

Comment: Can we really take Google's word for this?

Comment: @georgechalhoub Yes. If they were caught lying about it, there would be huge financial ramifications including anti-trust issues.

Comment: http://www.seoblog.com/2016/09/analytics-affect-rankings-seo/
what's your opinion? its logical google analytics helps crawlers indirectly,

Answer (score 1):

The small print in the Google Analytics agreement says Google can use the information it collects, leading to speculation that it might be a ranking factor. There has never been a shown correlation between analytics and ranking for a site using analytics.

Speculation also exists that the usage of information is used to provide AI with typical user interactions that AI can use when it sees other sites with pages that are similar, and it needs to make a guess as to the user interactions that the non-analytics page is getting. But doing better or worse than what was speculated is not factored back to the site.

There may also be public image concerns that ensure Google will never use that data as a ranking factor. If it was a factor others will feel forced to use their product ... not a good image and might even blow out of proportion into a political issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google Analytics data indirectly affects SEO. While Google Analytics itself does not directly impact search engine rankings, the insights and data it provides can help you make informed decisions to improve your website's performance, user experience, and content strategy. By analyzing Google Analytics data, you can identify areas for improvement, optimize your website for better user engagement, and ultimately enhance your SEO efforts.