# Does adding google analytics improve google ranking

Tags: google-analytics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Google Analytics data affect SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15909/does-google-analytics-data-affect-seo)

Does adding the google analytics .js file to a page improve it's google ranking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Matt Cutts himself said in a video that while Google does use Google Toolbar statistics to play a part in ranking, Analytics data (and therefor I assume the actual inclusion of ga.js) is completely left out of the equation.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZoesvNUPDQ